# How do I run sed in ExecuteProcess in Apache NiFi

Tags: bash, sed, dataflow, ogr2ogr, apache-nifi

I have csv log files that I convert to GeoJSON with `ogr2ogr` and then run `sed` against to clean up for elasticsearch.  Specifically:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output.json input.csv
sed -i -e '1,4d' -e '$d' output.json # delete first four lines and last line
sed -i '1 i\[' output.json # insert line with '[' at beginning of file
```

I would like to run these commands in NiFi but I have not had any luck configuring ExecuteProcess.

Comment: This Answer may help you out.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443101/nifi-how-to-reference-a-flowfile-in-executestreamcommand

Answer (score 3):

Try this method

```
seq 10 | sed -e '1,4d;$d;' -e '5 i\['
```

**OutPut:**

```
[
5
6
7
8
9
```