# NiFi: is there a way to execute line by line python code before we put in executescript?

Tags: apache-nifi

i am planning to write python code in executescript processor. As this is my first time, i am finding difficult to start.

basically, i want to read flowfile (csv) and do some manipulation and write it to flowfile.

is there a way where we can write the code beforehand, say suppose jupyter and then replicate the same in the processor?

also, is there any syntax documentation for writing the code?

**EXECUTESTREAMCOMMAND**:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.io
import csv 

# Get flowFile Session
flowFile = session.get()

# Open data.json file and parse json values
readFile = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
for row in readFile:
    new_value = row[0]
if (flowFile != None):
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "from_python_string", "python string example")
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "from_python_number", str(new_value))

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
session.commit()
```

---

```
Command Arguments: C:\Users\Desktop\samp1.py
Command Path: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python
```

when i execute it, it throws error on the import statement saying no module found.

tia

Comment: nice post to start with: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/75032/executescript-cookbook-part-1.html

Comment: i am using executestreamcommand and facing the error as i have updated in my question. please help me

Comment: if you are going to use executestreamcommand then you don't need to work with flowfiles. you will get flow file content as stdin and transformed content you have to write into stdout. so, you'll be able to debug your python script without nifi.

Comment: thanks @daggett. my python script is working with stdin and stdout. is there anyway to get the attribute values and update new attribute through python script in executestreamcommand processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt Burgess wrote a [script tester tool](https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2017/10/release-120-of-nifi-script-tester.html) which can accept a Jython script and test it. Not quite the interactive environment you're looking for, but probably as close as exists out of the box.

The code you write when using `ExecuteScript` and `ExecuteStreamCommand` will be very different; the core logic may be the same, but the way your code accesses and generates flowfile attributes and content will differ because when run outside of the NiFi runtime, Python has no awareness of the NiFi-specific features. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49524039/70465) for more details on how to write for `ExecuteStreamCommand` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448013/70465) for `ExecuteScript`.

Comment: thanks @Andy. my python script in ExecuteStreamCommand processor is working with stdin and stdout. is there anyway to get the attribute values and update new attribute?

Comment: You can pass attributes in as arguments, but there is currently no easy way to update an existing attribute with output.

Comment: thanks @Andy. final question, can we add new attributes?

Comment: You can use an `UpdateAttribute` processor or other processor like `EvaluateJSONPath` to update attributes later in the flow.